# Very simple XSL/XPath sanity check

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

This is going to be a really simple question I'm sure. I have an xml document that I'm transforming via XSL. The important part of this xml looks like this:

```
<root xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Transaction>
    <EnrollmentModel>
      <FutureContributionsModel>
        <FutureContributionsElectionType>ACertainThirdParty</FutureContributionsElectionType>
      </FutureContributionsModel>
    </EnrollmentModel>
  <Transaction>
</root>
```

And I want to add the following if the value of `<FutureContributionsElectionType>` does, in fact, equal `ACertainThirdParty`:

```
<fo:table-row>
    <fo:table-cell>
        <fo:block font-family="verdanaPS" font-size="9" padding-bottom="15px" padding-top="10px">
                        The Participant has successfully opted in to use ACertainThirdParty as the managed provider for the account.
        </fo:block>
    </fo:table-cell>
</fo:table-row>
```

Note that there is only one third party, so I don't need to get the value of the node for the custom text, I can just hard-code it in there.

If the value of `<FutureContributionsElectionType>` does NOT equal `ACertainThirdParty`, I wan't to add a whole bunch of other stuff.

***Here's what I tried:***

So this seems like a job for `<xsl:choose>` and `<xsl:when>` / `<xsl:otherwise>`, right?
Here's what I got:

```
<xsl:choose>
  <xsl:when test="FutureContributionsModel/FutureContributionsElectionType='ACertainThirdParty'">
    <fo:table-row>
      <fo:table-cell>
        <fo:block font-family="verdanaPS" font-size="9" padding-bottom="15px" padding-top="10px">
                        The Participant has successfully opted in to use ACertainThirdParty as the managed provider for the account.
        </fo:block>
      </fo:table-cell>
    </fo:table-row>
  </xsl:when>
  <xsl:otherwise>
    <fo:table-row>
      <fo:table-cell>
          ...
          Lots of stuff
          ...
      </fo:table-cell>
    </fo:table-row>
  </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

But when I transform it, the otherwise code gets hit rather than the correct code (in my xml the value is indeed `ACertainThirdParty`. My guess is my problem is that I don't know XPath, so I'm probably assuming I can do things that I can't. What's going on here?

Comment: Philip, we need to know the context node at least to tell whether the relative path starting with `FutureContributionsModel` is correct. So show us any `xsl:template match` and/or `xsl:for-each` that `xsl:choose` is in. And of course if there is any default namespace declaration (i.e. xmlns="http://example.com") on the input elements we need to know that as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably the context (current node) isn't `Transaction`.

You can use an absolute XPath expression:

```
/*/Transaction/EnrollmentModel/FutureContributionsModel/FutureContributionsElectionType='ACertainThirdParty'
```

**Much better, avoid using explicit conditionals -- use templates and template match patterns**:

```
<xsl:template match="FutureContributionsElectionType[.='ACertainThirdParty']">

  <!-- Specific Processing Here  -->
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="FutureContributionsElectionType[not(.='ACertainThirdParty')]">

  <!-- Other Specific Processing Here  -->
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: The absolute path didn't work, but I was able to get it like this:

 `<xsl:when test="//EnrollmentModel/FutureContributionsModel/FutureContributionElectionType='ACertainThirdParty'">`

Comment: @PhillipSchmidt, There is no `EnrollmentModel` in the provided XML document! And you have a typo. correctly noticed by Sicco. Now, I have corrected your typo in my answer and both proposed solutions should work. Please, update the question with the *real* XML document -- otherwise you are wasting your time and the time of the readers.

Comment: Sorry about that. I guess I was a bit hasty when copying over the XML. As this data is proprietary in nature, I can't copy and paste it, so I had to rewrite all of it, and must have missed `enrollmentmodel`.

Comment: I edited your answer with the correct structure, upvoted, and accepted. Nice answer.

Comment: @PhillipSchmidt: No problem, in such case one can use a small example, using completely different names -- that demonstrates the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this works as I don't use XSL, but I see 3 potential problems:

1. There is a typo in your XPath: 'FutureContributionElectionType' should be 'FutureContribution`s`ElectionType'
2. It is unclear if your XPath should start at 'FutureContributionsModel
   ' or earlier

Comment: 1) Sorry, the typo was introduced in writing the question. It doesn't exist in the original. 2) Yeah, it needed to start earlier. 3) It's fine the way it is on this one.